# Text to xml to simple table or dataframe

Tags: python, xml, text, python-3.5

Trying to re-polish my python skills (been working mostly in **R** until now) but ended up with a bunch of errors..

I want to download this the file from [here](http://utilitytool.casc.eu/CascUtilityWebService.asmx/GetNetPositionDataForAPeriod?dateFrom=2016-09-11&dateTo=2016-09-15) and convert it to a simple table (or dataframe). At first sight, it seems to be an xml file but python doesn't recognize it as an xml file. I tried this code:

```
import requests
url = 'http://utilitytool.casc.eu/CascUtilityWebService.asmx/GetNetPositionDataForAPeriod?dateFrom=2016-09-01&dateTo=2016-09-03'

r = requests.get(url)
print (r.content)
```

and it shows the data from that website in a text file format. Now I'd like to convert it to a simple table (or dataframe) with the column names: `ns1:CalendarDate, ns1:CalendarHour, ns1:BE, ns1:NL, ns1:DEAT` and `ns1:FR`

I googled a bunch of errors, tried all options from [here](https://penandpants.com/2012/03/09/reading-text-tables-with-python/) but still didn't find a solution..

Comment: Per the duplicate, requests does not parse xml, so you will need to use another module. The duplicate answer addresses this.

Comment: Try using beautifulsoup aka bs4. 
`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup; soup = Beautifulsoup(r.text)`. To help you get started check out their awesome tutorial: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/